# Add extra wordpress content between 2 php call functions

Tags: php, wordpress

I'd like to place some extra text content between my wordpress homepage-slider and the portfolio tiles, but can't figure out how to do it. My website is [www.20watt.nl](http://www.20watt.nl)

The main text content on my page sits *below* the portfolio tiles (as it should !) and is called out at the bottom of "home.php". But how do can I get *extra* text content between the slider en tiles and where can I then change the text in the future? (basically I want the tiles to have the main content below and a just a line or two above)

The callout order in my home.php is now slider->portfolio-tiles->content

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install this plugin: 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/multiple-content-blocks/

Then in home.php add this call:

```
<?php
the_block( 'extratext', array(
    'label'         => 'My extra text',
    'type'          => 'editor',
    'apply_filters' => true,
) );
?>
```

before this html line in home.php:

```
<div id="primary" class="content-area clr">
```

You maybe will have to tweak a bit the CSS then to make it appear clean.

Comment: Brilliant. Works perfect! Excellent and very useful solution! Problem solved :)